# How to pass the values of file columns to ILNumerics 3D graph?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I am working on a project Online Partial Discharge. I need to show a clear and professional graphs into it. So i Chose IlNumerics for it. Till installation, everything works fine.
Now i need to pass values to 3D graph for X, Y and Z axis from a file. How do i pass that data to 3D graph. How are arrays used is not clear in the documentation. 
It would be great if you help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: what have you done so far? You could post some code, describe what you are trying to achieve, what you expected, what was observed ... etc.

Comment: I have used gnuplot before. I have not been clear by the site of ilnumerics of how to do ilnumerics graph. Do they have any video with which i can pass values to ilnumerics code. Simple c# program

Comment: Commonly you 'pass' values as ILNumerics arrays. There is a ton of examples on the ILNumerics site. Check out some [examples](https://ilnumerics.net/examples.html) or read the [online documentation](https://ilnumerics.net/docs.html).